# How do I use a variable from another class in Unreal Script?

Tags: unreal-development-kit, unrealscript

I am working on a game, and that game has a battery life function for a flash light. Basically, when the flash light is turned on, it reduces the life and when it's off, it stops.

But to achieve this, I need to access a variable that will determine whether or not the flash light is turned on or off.

```
var UTWeap_FlashLight light;  // declaring a new variable from the class UTWeap_FlashLight.uc

// reduces battery life of the flash light
exec function ReducePower()
{
if(light.bCheck==true)
{
    if(0<power)  // loops till power 1 is = 0
    {
        power--;  // reduce the value of power

        if(power==0) // if it equals 0
        { 
            power2 = power2 - 1; // set power2 to it's own value - 1
            power=100; // reset power back to 100
        }
    }
  }
}
```

but whenever I compile the code, it tells me that it can't find the variable bCheck, meaning I can't check whether or not the flash light is on. I want to call that variable from this class

**UTWeap_FlashLight.uc**

```
exec function TurnOff()
{
    if(!Flashlight.LightComponent.bEnabled)
    {
        Flashlight.LightComponent.SetEnabled(true);
        bCheck = true; 
    }

    else
    {
        Flashlight.LightComponent.SetEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

this part of the code is where I turn on/off the flash light. When I turn it on, I want to set bCheck to 1 so I can then later use it as a condition to detect whether or not the flash light is on. But I can't use the variable, it will just not change it's value. I later found out you CAN'T use variables from other classes, which is pretty dumb. Any help appreciated.

Comment: How is the variable declared? Where are these two example code blocks located? What is the exact compile error and where (in that first block of code or in the second)? Are you getting any other compile errors?

Comment: Variable bCheck is declared in the custom class, UTWeap_FlashLight.uc first example block code is located in my custom hud class, MyHUD.uc second block is in the UTWeap_FlashLight.uc which is responsible for turning on/off my flash light. No I'm not getting any errors, it's just not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I figured out how to use variables from other classes in unreal script.

IF you're wondering how to do the same use this:

```
class'<yourclassname>'.default.<yourvariablename>; // remove the < >
```